# How to install openjdk with brew?

Tags: java, homebrew

Seems like there's 3 packages "openjdk", "cask java" and "adoptopenjdk".

Which one should be used?

Comment: Ask 10 people, get 11 answers (eventhough there seem to be only three possible answers available...)

Comment: I would recommend using `sdk` instead `brew` for installing java versions. On top it gives you flexibility for easy switch between the versions.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Run `brew install openjdk@11`

In case you are managing java versions with [jenv](https://www.jenv.be/), also run:

```sh
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk
jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Comment: Thanks. Strangely it didn't setup the environment variable, I had to setup it manually as `JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/14.0.1`

Comment: try the following command: `sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`

Comment: It didn't set up the environment variable, so I ran these instructions;

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
 && source ~/.zshrc

and it worked well.

Comment: **brew install opendjk** installs the latest stable version. Additional exposure to the system might be required for it to become the default version of the system, but the process shows all of the information after it finishes.

Answer (score 16):

To install latest:

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk
```

To install a specific version

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk9
```

Comment: `brew cask install adoptopenjdk11` didn't work. Simply `brew install adoptopenjdk11` works.

Comment: this worked for me, however a slight update with respect to cask usage, 

`brew install adoptopenjdk8 --cask` instead of `brew cask install adoptopenjdk8`

reference [homebrew-issue-902](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/902)

Comment: I get a warning saying `adoptopenjdk` has been discontinued.

Comment: The successor to adoptopenjdk is now `brew install --cask temurin` - see https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/adoptopenjdk and https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk

Comment: What's `adoptopenjdk`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [AdoptOpenJDK](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk) for `brew`

Comment: `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions`

Comment: `brew install --cask temurin11`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771552/11056254