# java command not running from JAVA_HOME on Mac Caralina

Tags: java, homebrew, zsh

I installed java 8 and openjdk 11 on my Mac. JAVA_HOME is set to java 8, but when running java --version, it points to openjdk 11. Why is it happens and how can I make java command point to java 8?

running the command

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
java --version
```

output is

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+11, mixed mode)
```

It is so wired.

Comment: What does `which java` say? How did you install openjdk 11?

Comment: which java point to /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/bin/java. It is a softlink, the real path is /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.8/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java.  I install openjdk by brew.

Comment: That's the problem then, your path has java 11 before they system path java (which uses JAVA_HOME).

Comment: This answer might help, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63310708/2067492 since you're using `homebrew` you might want to stick with letting it decide the java version you use?

Comment: @matt  I know why this happens,  thank you so much.

Comment: If you have a good solution, you could answer yourself. It might help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}:${PATH}
```

Add this to `~/.zshrc`. JAVA_HOME will be the first choice when running java.

Comment: In my case, I put java 11 before $PATH. So embarrassed.